# General way to apply an arbitrary method to all subgoals?

Tags: isabelle

Suppose I have a list of subgoals in an apply style proof. I know that something like

```
    apply blast
```

will provide a proof for a number of the subgoals within this list. Is there a way I can avoid duplicating this line?

For example, suppose I have three subgoals where the first and the third are provable using the above method while the second is provable with something like

```
    apply (metis lemma1 lemma2 ...)
```

A naive proof for such subgoals will look like

```
    apply blast
    apply (metis lemma1 lemma2 ...)
    apply blast
```

What I am looking for is a way to give a proof without duplicating the `apply blast` portion of the proof. Observe that using the method combinator `+` will not achieve this; it merely applies the method repeatedly until the first failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `apply blast` will only try to solve the first subgoal. If you want to solve as many subgoals as possible you could try

```
apply blast+
```

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but an alternative to your `using some_lemma` might be

```
apply (insert some_lemma)
```

which inserts `some_lemma` as additional assumption of all of your subgoals.

**Update:** There are some basic proof method combinators available in Isabelle (see also Section 6.4.1: Proof method expressions, of isar-ref). So you could do for example

```
apply (blast | metis ...)+
```

which will first try to solve a subgoal by `blast` and only if this fails by `metis ...`. However, its usefulness depends on the specific subgoal situation, e.g., if `blast` takes a long time before failing, it might not be suitable. More fine-grained control of proof methods is available through the recent Isabelle/Eisbach proof method language (see `isabelle doc eisbach`).

Comment: `+` requires the first application to succeed and then repeatedly applies the method until failure. This will not be useful in the particular scenario I have in mind. I have edited my question to make what I am looking for more clear.

Comment: This could work. Another solution would be to capture all duplicate subgoals in lemmas and add them to the intro set of auto.